# From what tantric book is this illustration from?

Tags: identification-request, tantra

From what tantric book is this illustration from
[image]

Comment: There are thousands of books if you post any random then it would be too general to tell the book

Comment: It looks like tge depiction of the Ajna Chakra as seen from a Buddhist Tantra.

Comment: I'm not sure specifically where it is from, it seems to be from 18th Century Rajasthan - Here is a fuller picture which contains Crown, Brow and Throat Chakras -> https://bit.ly/2HPoycw

Comment: Seems like Budhist meditation technique

Answer (score 4):

From a reverse image search, I found out this image is the front cover of the book *[Tantra : The Indian Cult Of Ecstasy Philip Rawson](https://archive.org/details/TantraTheIndianCultOfEcstasyPhilipRawson)*

The full image is below

[image: This is a gouache painting of subtle body with its chakras]

This image is found in page 86 of the same book. The image description in the book is given as:

> 47 The Subtle body with its chakras (detail). Nepal. 17<sup>th</sup>  century. gouache on paper. complete diagram 140 X 11 in.

So, the answer is it is a [gouache painting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gouache) from Nepal dated 17<sup>th</sup> century explaining chakras in our body in detail.